# Can I put a collection or array into the where clause on laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

```
$collection=["c","a","f","h","j","o","k"]

$total_sums=Models::select('count')->whereIn('class',['c','a','f','h','j','o','k'])
                    ->get()
                    ->sum('count');
```

can I use variable $collection like this?

```
$total_sums=Models::select('count')->whereIn('class',[''.$collection.''])
                    ->get()
                    ->sum('count');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use both.

[whereIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#where-clauses) accepts both `Array` and a `Collection`.
You just simply pass it as a second parameter.

```php
$array = ["c","a","f","h","j","o","k"];
$collection = collect($array);

$total_sums=Models::select('count')->whereIn('class', $array)
            ->get()
            ->sum('count');

// works

$total_sums=Models::select('count')->whereIn('class', $collection)
            ->get()
            ->sum('count');

// also works!
```

Comment: In fact, you can use everything that is Arrayable.

Comment: Good catch! Though, Array is not Arrayable :D

Comment: Seems logical though, an array is already an array, it cannot be transformed into an array :)

Comment: Thanks~ Can  use 'like' in whereIn clause which using collection? If I want to use where and like with a collection.

Answer (score 1):

No because `$collection` is already an array.  When you try to concatenate it to a string, I believe your query will look like the following...

```
select count from models where class in ('Array');
```

What you probably actually want to do is...

```
->whereIn('class', $collection)
```